# Cannot select text in Kendo Sortable with handle

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, selection, jquery-ui-sortable, textselection

I have a set of sortable widgets, very similar to this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/sortable-panels). JS inits here:

```
    var column1Sortable = $(column1Selector).kendoSortable({
        filter: ".panel",
        cursor: "move",
        handler: ".panel-header",
        connectWith: column2Selector,
        change: sortableOnChange,
        placeholder: sortablePlaceholder,
        hint: sortableHint
    }).data("kendoSortable");
    var column2Sortable = $(column2Selector).kendoSortable({
        filter: ".panel",
        cursor: "move",
        handler: ".panel-header",
        connectWith: column1Selector,
        change: sortableOnChange,
        placeholder: sortablePlaceholder,
        hint: sortableHint
    }).data("kendoSortable");
```

HTML for the panels look similar to this:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-header">Header</div>
    <div class="panel-content">
        ... selectable text here ...
    </div>
</div>
```

While I've set a `handler` option to the `.panel-header` div, I cannot select any text within the `.panel-content` area. The mouse cursor shows the text cursor, but upon trying to highlight, nothing is highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use the `ignore` option and use a high-level selector with the "select all" selector `*`. Here's what my JS init calls look like now:

```
    var column1Sortable = $(column1Selector).kendoSortable({
        filter: ".panel",
        cursor: "move",
        handler: ".panel-header",
        ignore: ".panel-contents *",
        connectWith: column2Selector,
        change: sortableOnChange,
        placeholder: sortablePlaceholder,
        hint: sortableHint
    }).data("kendoSortable");
    var column2Sortable = $(column2Selector).kendoSortable({
        filter: ".panel",
        cursor: "move",
        handler: ".panel-header",
        ignore: ".panel-contents *",
        connectWith: column1Selector,
        change: sortableOnChange,
        placeholder: sortablePlaceholder,
        hint: sortableHint
    }).data("kendoSortable");
```

Comment: I thought it was logical that, like in your case, setting the ignore property to `".panel-contents"` would also ignore all its children, but nope. Adding the `*` to mine also fixed the issue. Thank you!